# ingress routing api prefix issue

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

```
paths:
  - backend:
      serviceName: booknotes-front-end-service
      servicePort: 80
    path: /
  - backend:
      serviceName: booknotes-back-end-service
      servicePort: 3000
    path: /api
```

Here is a rules in my ingres-nginx resource . I try to direct all traffic which starts from `/api` to my back end service, which works properly, but if some route in my back end will be like /api/users it doesn't work , my back end send response not found , when I run it locally this route working properly. Also I've tried delete /api prefix from my koa routing and change it to `/users` and then I've also changed  `path: /api` to `path: /users` and this stuff are working properly. What should I do for fixing it ? If you need additional info , pls let me know !

Answer (score 8):

Which version of nginx-ingress are you using?
They changed the way for defining a path.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

> Starting in Version 0.22.0, ingress definitions using the annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target are not backwards compatible with previous versions. In Version 0.22.0 and beyond, any substrings within the request URI that need to be passed to the rewritten path must explicitly be defined in a capture group.

For example you can use a definition like this.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: some-ingress-name
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /?(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: booknotes-front-end-service
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /api/?(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: booknotes-back-end-service
            servicePort: 3000
```

Comment: I use this version - 0.26.1

Comment: You should use rewrite as described in the above link. I added an example configuration to my answer.

Comment: Important is the additional annotation with the placeholder which is replaced with a value based on the path regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is searching for the file `/api/users`, which probably doesn't exist.

Put a file in `/api/users/`, in the backends of the service `booknotes-back-end-service`, say `user1`, and make the requeat explicitly to `/api/users/user1`.

You should get 200 there.

Answer (score -1):

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer , section step6 try  replacing path /api with /api/* and / with /*

Comment: it sends me then to the first service

Comment: did you try with rewrite-target ?