# Kubernetes Ingress gets Error while it works in minikube ssh

Tags: kubernetes

I am testing kubernetes with minikube on centOS 7, following the follow progress:

1. Build 2 docker images running simple backend with express.js
2. Running deployment to serve totally 4 pods, 2 of each image respectively
3. Serving service with the pods
4. Using ingress to access the services

When I gets into the minikube by `minikube ssh`, the APIs all work properly.
However, outside of it, it always get error.
So guess it must be error in 3 or 4?  But it doesn't get connection error (as it once was before setup properly).  Can it be security settings or what?

---

Settings & results as below:

- deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: abc
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: abc
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: image/abc
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: abc
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: efg
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: efg
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: image/efg
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: efg
```

- service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: abc-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: abc
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: efg-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: efg
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
```

- ingress.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /abc
            backend:
              serviceName: abc-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /efg
            backend:
              serviceName: efg-service
              servicePort: 80
```

- `kubectl describe` result:

```
Name:             web
Namespace:        default
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host         Path    Backends
  ----         ----    --------
  my.host.com
               /abc    abc-service:80 (172.18.0.4:3000,172.18.0.6:3000)
               /efg    efg-service:80 (172.18.0.5:3000,172.18.0.7:3000)
Annotations:   Events
  Type         Reason  Age               From                      Message
  ----         ------  ----              ----                      -------
  Normal       CREATE  24m               nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/web
  Normal       UPDATE  3s (x4 over 23m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/web
```

- `minikube ip` gets `172.17.0.4`
- /etc/hosts

```
172.17.0.4    my.host.com
```

- Running `curl 172.18.0.4:3000` gets the expected result (json) successfully
- Running `curl my.host.com/abc`, it gets

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /abc</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try by changing service type to clusterIP instead of nodeport.

Comment: can you check `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`  annotations, like https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource

Comment: Did you enable ingress addon in minikube?

Comment: Hi @hoque thanks it helps to access the "root api" (with path set as `/`) of the service.  However, every child api (with path `/xxx/`) are all headed to the root api.  I will find other solution for this new issue.  But this helps to access the service, thanks!

Comment: @hariK yes ingress already enabled in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally my kubernetes works.  Here to sum up the progress:

1. As suggestion in comments above, add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` in annotations of ingress.yaml
2. But then the new issue was that, every route maps samely to the root api of each service.  Here's the solution: [ingress routing api prefix issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673051/ingress-routing-api-prefix-issue)

Finally my new ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /abc/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: abc-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /efg/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: efg-service
              servicePort: 80
```

Then I can now access my APIs:

- `my.host.com/abc/` (one thing to highlight is that the final `/` is required here, otherwise it gets 404 Error)
- `my.host.com/abc/child`
- `my.host.com/efg/`
- `my.host.com/efg/child`

May be somehow helpful for others also new to K8s now or after.